# need to create a phonegap project for blackberry in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, blackberry

i have creatde the `phonegap 2.9` application in `android` , now i want to create the BlackBerry build.

I have downloaded following things

`BlackBerry JAVA SDK for version 7 and 5` in `Eclipse`  as i want to make build for BlackBerry 5.0

[WebWorks SDK 2.0](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/sdk/) (installed it independently and dont know how can i use it in eclipse )

now i dont know what to do next i feel like m missing the road map , i want to create a blackberry project and want to copy all js and html files into it and want to check it on a simulator.

i read on this [blog](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/how-to-create-blackberry-webwork-phonegap-project-in-eclipse/)that i need to create a `WebWorks` project in eclipse but  i dont see anything when i click on create project in eclipse. ( i am aware that `WebWorks` support of eclipse no longer supported )

so can any one tell me how do i create a black berry build

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already set the path of SDK in "System Properties". Did you?

Comment: Which path can you please elaborate ?

Comment: i am talking about "Environment Variables".